# How do I construct a non-linear model from experimental data?

Tags: fitting

I want to find a function $w=f(x,y,z)$ that fits experimentally determined values of w.

For example, assume

```
x = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2}

y = {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}

z = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

and experiments have given

```
w = {.531, .341, .163, .641, .713, -0.40e-1}
```

I want to fit this data according to this relationship:

```
w = x^a + (b x^2)/y + c y z
```

How can I find the constants a, b and c and estimate the error the model produces?

Comment: `NonlinearModelFit` will help you out.  You have to take care with your symbol definitions, though, if the data you are passing to `NonlinearModelFit` is in the symbol `x`, then the value should not also be called x.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is certainly answered in another elsewhere on the site, but I can't find a simple example.

**1. Ensure proper formatting**

If you wish to have your experimental data in the symbols `x`, `y`, and `z`, then these symbols cannot show up in your model.  Adjust the model slightly such as this:

```
x = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2}
y = {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}
z = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
w = {.531, .341, .163, .641, .713, -0.040}
model = x1^a + (b x1^2)/y1 + c y1 z1
```

Also make sure that your numbers are interpreted as numbers by *Mathematica*.  The last term in `w` needs to be fixed.

**2. Follow the documentation**

The documentation for [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html) is pretty good and provides you with examples as well as the summary statistics that can be easily extracted after the fitting is complete.

`NonlinearModelFit` wants the data entered in the format {{xi, yi, zi, wi}, {...},...} which can be achieved easily with `Transpose`

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[Transpose[{x,y,z,w}],model,{a,b,c},{x1,y1,z1}]
```

**3. View Results**

By assigning `NonlinearModelFit` to a symbol, you can easily access summary statistics as well as the information in which you are interested:

```
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
nlm["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hey, man! You _should_ teach science! :)